# Calculating First Working Day adding holidays

Tags: algorithm, datetime, math, automation

I need to find the first working day of the month. Ideally it should be `01/MM/YYYY` but the condition is that it should not be a `Saturday` or `Sunday` or a day from the `List of Holidays`.

List being:

```
ListOfHoliday
Name     Day
Someday  01/01/2021
Someday  01/02/2021
Someday  31/03/2021
Someday  04/07/2021
Someday  25/12/2021
```

I was trying to use the below algo:

```
FWD = Text.concat(01, DateTime.CurrentMonthOfToday, DateTime.CurrentyearOfToday)
foreach(holiday in ListOfHoliday)
{
  if (FWD == holiday) 
  {
    DateTime.AddDays(ConvertTo.DateTime(FWD), 1)
    if (ConvertTo.DateTime(FWD).DayOftheWeek == Saturday) 
    {
      FWD=ConvertTo.Text(DateTime.AddDays(ConvertTo.DateTime(FWD), 2));
    } else 
    {
      if ((ConvertTo.DateTime(FWD).DayOftheWeek == Sunday)) 
      {
        FWD=ConvertTo.Text(DateTime.AddDays(ConvertTo.DateTime(FWD), 2));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But the result I get for the current month is 01/01/0001.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the python code to find the first working day of a given month.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def working_day(temp,holid):
  if temp.strftime('%A') == 'Saturday':
    temp += timedelta(2)
    return working_day(temp,holid)
  elif temp.strftime('%A') == 'Sunday' or temp in holid:
    temp += timedelta(1)
    return working_day(temp,holid)
  else:
    return temp.strftime('%A')

date_format = "%d/%m/%Y"
holidays =  ['01/01/2021','01/02/2021','31/03/2021','04/07/2021','25/12/2021']
holid = []
for day in holidays:
  holid.append(datetime.strptime(day, date_format))

month = int(input('Enter the month'))    # input should be 1,2,3....12
today ='01/'+str(month)+'/2021'
today  = datetime.strptime(today, date_format)
print(working_day(today, holid))
```

output:

Enter the month 12

Wednesday